# Using the name of a table contained in a column of another table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `MyTable` with varchar columns named `SourceID` and `ReferenceID`, where `SourceID` contains a table name and `ReferenceID` contains a key value for the source table.

Is it possible in a query to refer to the source table's row assuming I know the name of the key column that matches the value in `RefrenceID`?

Sample:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable as MT
INNER JOIN MT.SourceID as Src ON MT.ReferenceID = Src.InstanceID
```

This doesn't work, obviously.  But is there a way to do this as opposed to dynamically building the SQL statement using the values of `SourceID` and `ReferenceID` and then executing the query?  More specifically, is there a way to make `MyTable.SourceID` in the example above be usable within the JOIN?

#### Further considerations

I found [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/03/Conditional-Joins.aspx), and it has a trick like follows:

```
select
  E.EmployeeName, coalesce(s.store,o.office) as Location
from
  Employees E
left outer join 
  Stores S on ...
left outer join
  Offices O on ...
where
  O.Office is not null OR S.Store is not null
```

The WHERE clause simply helps the outer joins behave like INNER JOINs.  This would work well enough if there were a limited number of table options and they all had UNIQUE constraints.  This gets me part of the way there but but I **really** want is to have the table names in the JOINs to be based on a column in `Employees`.

I haven't given up yet. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is to query SourceID in to a variable and then query the source table. At that point, you're better off pulling both into variablesm like this:

```
DECLARE @SourceTable NVARCHAR(255) --Note the length is arbitrary
,@SourceID NVARCHAR(255) --Assuming it's an INT, it doesn't matter
,@sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SourceTable = SourceID
,@SourceID = ReferenceID
FROM MyTable
WHERE SourceID = 'some_table'
AND ReferenceID = 1

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @SourceTable + ' WHERE InstanceID = ' + @SourceID

EXEC(@sql)
```

You want the SourceID to be a string because otherwise you'd need to convert it to one anyway.

Comment: The last two lines of your code are very close to where I ended up.  I am hoping someone identifies a way to do it without the use of EXEC().

Comment: `SP_EXECUTESQL` is the only other way...how else would the query get executed?

Comment: From SSMS in a query window or through another application.  I'm looking for an "inline" solution if there is one.

Comment: 1) PRINT the value of @sql, copy it into the query window and execute it. 2) Write a commandline app in your favorite language to execute against the database. 3) Possibly powershell, osql or something similar to execute the statements.